# How to get the setOnCheckedChangeListener (ListView Checkboxes to work)

Tags: java, android

I flagged the other thread to be deleted, because the main question was edited so many times, that it become confusing.

So the problem is: I want to populate a ListView with checkboxes, and as I want to customize my ListView I'm not using simple_multiple_choice_mode, I'm putting my layout on list_item.xml: (for each row)

```
      <CheckBox>
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingLeft="8mm"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_removed"    android:id="@+id/nomeAPP" style="?listItem"&gt;
                    </<CheckBox>
```

My ListView is on lista.xml

```
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?whiteBackground">
```

my adapter:

```
      list=getListView();
                 this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt;(this,
                        R.layout.list_item, aux))
```

So I'm trying to make a setOnCheckedChangeListener for the checkboxes, so I can store the chosed items in an array.

So I did this listener :

```
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), &quot;Checked&quot;,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                         else
                        {
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), &quot;UnChecked&quot;,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }

                    }
                  });
```

Problem is: I get the NULL exception. The **CURIOUS** thing is: if I "switch" my layout for a simple

```
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/widget54" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
   <CheckBox android:text="Checkbox" android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox> 
    </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

And forget my ListView (and my adapter), it works! So, what's wrong with my layout?

I created a new little project just to let you guys see exactly the situation. It's available [HERE](http://db.tt/3aMQ4PC) Right now does not work, but if you uncomment the adapter, change ListActivity to Activity and change setContentView, it will work (checked/unchecked toast text).

Another curious thing I found is that with ListActivity does not work never.... wondering if it's related...

Comment: can you post the null exception log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think i got your problem,

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
```

This works in the second layout, because you might have already set the view for the activity using setcontentview().

So , the problem in your list activity is that , the above mentioned line doesn't know , which layout it has to look for to find id,

```
R.id.CheckBox01
```

you have to get access to the layout view which you are inflating the listview , lets call it a `inflatedView`, and then you access the check box like this.

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
```

if you don't set the content view, you have to tell the function findViewById(), where it has to look for the view. 
I would confirm this, if you post the NPE log.

HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately there's something missing in your thinking - is that, setContentView(R.Layout.Lista) is present for the "first situation", so the app knows where is the ListView and the adapter knows where is each row with the R.layout.List_item.... Even so, I tried to use your solution but I'm not sure how to adapt. What should I do before that line? Because inflatedView is a variable of something... a view? @yashwanthkumar you have all the code available if you want to have a looks..

Comment: follow the 2 links, i think they will help you in accessing your check box in right way, the idea is that you have to access the check box in the getView() method, http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html , http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Thanks. I'm now having some problems customizing the adapter but I'm sure that's the way.